# Add attribute to XML Element

Tags: xml, vb6, attributes, xmldom

I am trying to add attributes to an XML Element. I cannot seem to get it working.

```vb
Public Sub fnWriteXML(DATA)
  Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Dim oNode As IXMLDOMProcessingInstruction
  Dim sDC As String
  Dim xAtt1 As IXMLDOMAttribute
  Dim xAtt2 As IXMLDOMAttribute
  Dim xAtt3 As IXMLDOMAttribute
  Dim xAtt4 As IXMLDOMAttribute

  sDC = """

  'oDoc.async = False
  oDoc.validateOnParse = False
  oDoc.resolveExternals = False
  oDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = True
  'Processing Instruction
  Set oNode = oDoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
  oDoc.appendChild(oNode)
  Set oNode = Nothing

  ' Create Top Level kfx
  Dim XMLREL As IXMLDOMElement
  Set XMLREL = oDoc.createElement("cus.XMLRELEASE")
  'Add attribute
  Set xAtt1 = oDoc.createAttribute("xmlns:cus")
  xAtt1.Value = "http://www.myurl.com"
  xAtt1.appendChild(XMLREL)
  oDoc.appendChild(XMLREL)

  oDoc.Save("E:\TestXML\Test.xml")
End Sub
```

The above example the line:

```
xAtt1.appendChild(XMLREL)
```

Fails for Type Mismatch.

How do I add one or more attributes to an element? I am building this XML from a series of values in the source application.

Comment: The code you posted is not VBScript. Also, *always* include the complete error message.

Comment: ...That is VB...
and the Error is 10080 Type Mismatch

XMLREL.setAttribute(xAtt1,xAtt1.value) -> ((10080) Type mismatch.)

Comment: ANSWER:

Dim XMLREL As IXMLDOMElement
      Set XMLREL = oDoc.createElement("kfx.XMLRELEASE")
      oDoc.appendChild(XMLREL)
      'Add attribute
      XMLREL.setAttribute("xmlns.kfx","http:\\www.myurl.com")

Comment: You may want to post that as an actual answer.